# Azure Traffic Manager alerts configuration for service endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I’d like to configure an alert on a TM profile with 6 app services endpoints that uses the ‘queries by endpoint returned’ metric to generate an alert if an endpoint is returned less than 20% of its lowest value over the past month for a period longer than 3 mins.

Configuring alerts in the Azure portal looks very basic so was wondering whether this is possible and whether anyone had some similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. Check the microsoft documentation - Traffic Manager metrics and alerts.

### Alerts on Traffic Manager metrics

> In addition to processing and
>   displaying metrics from Traffic Manager, Azure Monitor enables
>   customers to configure and receive alerts associated with these
>   metrics. You can choose what conditions need to be met in these
>   metrics for an alert to occur, how often those conditions need to be
>   monitored, and how the alerts should be sent to you. Alerts on Traffic
>   Manager metrics In addition to processing and displaying metrics from
>   Traffic Manager, Azure Monitor enables customers to configure and
>   receive alerts associated with these metrics. You can choose what
>   conditions need to be met in these metrics for an alert to occur, how
>   often those conditions need to be monitored, and how the alerts should
>   be sent to you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-metrics-alerts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/metrics-custom-overview

Comment: Thanks for that, I had a look at that doc prior to posting and I’ve created basic alerts based on the two metrics available for traffic manager. Problem I’m having is that the criteria options via the portal seem very limited so was wondering if there was additional options available elsewhere... dynamic thresholds for example?

Comment: I don't have a working solution. You may be able to collect the metrics yourself, aggregate the data and then have a custom alert for the result. You could probably accomplish this with a runbook.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I’ve managed to do this fairly easily in New Relic by gathering stats from the endpoint being hit. Seems Azure alerting has a long way to go before it could be used to monitor production services effectively.

Comment: Noticed a lot of inconsistent behaviour in Azure with alerts as well. Alert emails generated but no alert in the portal etc. Think we’ll stick with our other monitoring solutions for now!

Comment: I couldn't agree more about Azure alerting. I came from AWS. Alerting and metrics seemed to have been in the forefront of their minds when they started. It was intuitive to build the features you're talking about. I'll have to look into "New Relic". Right now I'm trying to convince my employer to fork over the money for third-party monitoring.